# jQuery UI autocomplete in AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery UI autocomplete that I'm trying to resolve with a lot of research and only resolved it partialy. I've managed to make it work at all with this code:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { name: request.term },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm working with open source API in JSON, here is an example:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 436,
      "license_author": "Andrew Carothers",
      "status": "1",
      "description": "<p>1 Minute for each exercise</p>\n<ol>\n<li>Hold feet 6 inches off ground</li>\n<li>Crunches</li>\n<li>Side Crunches (L)</li>\n<li>Side Crunches (R)</li>\n<li>Heel Touches</li>\n<li>Plank Crunch</li>\n<li>Scissor Kicks</li>\n<li>Swim Kicks</li>\n<li>V Crunches</li>\n<li>Hold feet 6 in off ground</li>\n</ol>\n<p>Exercises can be substituted to vary workout</p>",
      "name": "10 Min Abs",
      "name_original": "10 Min Abs",
      "creation_date": "2016-12-09",
      "uuid": "3c5f6e1c-cb22-4a9f-a13e-d14afeb29175",
      "license": 2,
      "category": 10,
      "language": 2,
      "muscles": [],
      "muscles_secondary": [],
      "equipment": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get autocomplete suggestions with letters from "name" in JSON, but instead I've got whole JSON array, even with non-existing objects. I've already tried `item.results[0].name`, but everything I've got is `TypeError: item.results is undefined`. **How to modify `$.ajax` to get "name" value of JSON object in autocomplete suggestions**?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The errors you are getting suggests that the data object you gave us isn't what you are receiving. We can't help you without a real representation of the data you are receiving.

Comment: @KevinB Well, I check Firefox's Network Monitor every time and I'm getting good URL, in json type, for example https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&name=10+Min+Abs

Comment: data.results.map(...

Answer (score 0):

does this work :

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json",
                type: "GET",
                data: { name: request.term },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.results, function(index,item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, I've already tried that and the response is `TypeError: item is null`

Comment: in $.each callback first arg is index and second is the value, sorry my bad

Comment: Okay, it works, but the suggestion appears only when you type 100% correct name in input, it doesn't suggest anything before the name is correct, because the script is looking in non-existing JSON arrays.